# Provided fortran 95 example codes aren't compiling

Tags: fortran, fortran95

I've been reading this guide, and compiling ANY of their example codes consistently gives errors with the write section: http://www.mrao.cam.ac.uk/~rachael/compphys/SelfStudyF95.pdf

```
program vertical
!
! Vertical motion under gravity
!
implicit none
! acceleration due to gravity
real, parameter :: g = 9.8
! variables
real :: s ! displacement
real :: t ! time
real :: u ! initial speed ( m / s)
! set values of variables
t = 6.0
u = 60
! calculate displacement
s = u * t - g * (t**2) / 2
! output results
write(*,*) ’Time = ’,t,’ Displacement = ’,s
end program vertical
```

Compiling this code generates an error message of "Expected expression in WRITE statement"

The "Hello World" example also fails to compile.

```
program ex1
!
! My first program
!
write(*,*) ’Hello there’
end program ex1
```

Yet when I go by Wikibook's style and rewrite the example code to this: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fortran/Hello_world

```
program ex1
!
! My first program
!
print *, "Hello there"
end program ex1
```

It compiles correctly.

On a side note, what's the difference between "print" and "write"? I have prior basic experience with C and Matlab.

EDIT: I was rewriting a C programming assignment into a Fortran program. This code compiled correctly:

```
program ex1

integer :: number_one, number_two, num3

real :: number_onef, number_twof, num3f, num4f

character (LEN=10) :: name

print*, "Enter two integers"

read (*,*) number_one, number_two

write(*,*), 'the number you entered is        ', number_one
write(*,*), 'the second number you entered is ', number_two

num3 = number_one * number_two

write(*,*), 'Multiplied result:               ' ,num3

print*, "Enter two floating point numbers"

read (*,*) number_onef, number_twof

write(*,*) 'the number you entered is       ', number_onef
write(*,*) 'the second number you entered is', number_twof

num3f = number_onef * number_twof

write(*,*) 'Multiplied result:             ', num3f

num4f = number_onef / number_twof

write(*,*) 'Divided result:                  ', num4f

print*, "Enter your name"

read (*,*) name

write (*,*) 'Hello ', name
```

Comment: Which fortran compiler are you using and what command are you issuing to do the compilation?

Comment: I installed codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup.exe and selected the Fortran compiler that came with the downloaded package. On a side note, how do I determine if the compiler is Fortran 90, 95, or 2003?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should check which compiler you are using. I have no experience with Code::Blocks but the Wiki should help you:
[Supported Compiler](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Installing_a_supported_compiler)

If you want to change the Compiler (to gfortran (GNU) for example, since it seems to use g77 for default), see:
[Change Compiler](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Installing_Fortran_Compiler#Using_gfortran_instead_of_g77)

You can check the features of your compiler (90, 95, 03, 08) on the Fortran Wiki.

The GNU compiler supports the '95 standard and a large number of features from the 2003 standard. It is free and there is an installation instruction in the Wiki link above so you should give it a try.

Your question is hard to answer unless we know, what compiler you are using.

> On a side note, what's the difference between "print" and "write"?

**write** can be used to write to standard output or to a file while **print** writes to standard output. In the context of your examples, both statements can be used. There is no difference (using Intel fortran compiler and GNU at least) in using

```
print *, "hello"
print *, 'hello'
write(*,*) "hello"
write(*,*) 'hello'
write(*,*), ...
```

however i'd recommend against mixing it up.

Comment: I believe I'm using the GCC compiler (version 4.7.1, 32 bit), based on the information provided in the Codeblocks download page. http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26